# How do you swap/remove actions in the app bar in flutter when you have no access to the scaffold?

Tags: flutter, mobile, dart, flutter-layout

I'm in the following situation:

I have a scaffold with an appbar and a tab bar, and in the body of the scaffold I have my TabBarView with two stateful widgets as tabs, as shown below

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: "First"),
              Tab(text: "Second"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            FirstWidget(),
            SecondWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now each widget has to define its own actions to be added to the app bar, how do you idiomatically set the right actions to the parent scaffold? I've tried creating a custom tabController and listening for events, and swapping the buttons at runtime, but it seems like giving responsibilities to the tab controller on its children Behaviour and inner logics.
Is there a way to query for the scaffold and set the actions to the app bar (end eventually the floating actionButton) from within the children widgets (in the example I'm referring to `FirstWidget` and `SecondWidget`).

I was looking for sometihing like `Scaffold.of(context).setAppBarActions(...)`.
I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791044/hot-to-refresh-actions-of-appbar-on-tab-change) which is very similar, however I do not agree with the solution because it requires the father scaffold to have knowledge (and generate) widgets with behaviour relative to its children, and I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use package provider to get functionality like `Scaffold.of(context).setAppBarActions(...)`.

Using `child` is important to avoid rebuilding the `TabBarView` each time you want the `AppBar` to rebuild.

Getting access to `context` in the `FirstWidget` and `SecondWidget` is a pain since `context` is not available in `initState` so a post frame callback has to be used.

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ActionWidgets with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Widget> _widgets = <Widget>[];

  UnmodifiableListView<Widget> get widgets {
    return UnmodifiableListView<Widget>(this._widgets);
  }

  set widgets(final List<Widget> widgets) {
    this._widgets = widgets;
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<ActionWidgets>(
            create: (final BuildContext buildContext) {
              return ActionWidgets();
            },
          ),
        ],
        child: Consumer<ActionWidgets>(
          builder: (final BuildContext context, final ActionWidgets actionWidgets, final Widget child) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: const Text("My Home Page"),
                actions: actionWidgets.widgets,
                bottom: TabBar(
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: "First (comm)"),
                    Tab(text: "Second (social)"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              body: child,
            );
          },
          child: TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              FirstWidget(),
              SecondWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstWidgetState createState() {
    return _FirstWidgetState();
  }
}

class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((final Duration _) {
      final ActionWidgets actionWidgets = Provider.of<ActionWidgets>(this.context, listen: false);
      actionWidgets.widgets = <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.email),
        Icon(Icons.phone),
      ];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("First Widget (communication)"));
  }
}

class SecondWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondWidgetState createState() {
    return _SecondWidgetState();
  }
}

class _SecondWidgetState extends State<SecondWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((final Duration _) {
      final ActionWidgets actionWidgets = Provider.of<ActionWidgets>(this.context, listen: false);
      actionWidgets.widgets = <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.group),
        Icon(Icons.person_add),
      ];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("Second Widget (social)"));
  }
}
```

Comment: setAppBarActions() doesnt exist

Comment: @chitgoks That's exactly why I answered the question.

Comment: yes, right. that is weird. having to install provider just to expose a method from a different class